# != operator not working as it should

Tags: c#

I am currently trying to get my snake console game running but I have came up with something that I do not quite understand. I don't really think that the `!=` operator is not working correctly, so I must have made a mistake but I have no idea why it it is like that:

```
 // not working
 if (food.x != snakeElements.Last().x && food.y != snakeElements.Last().y) 

 // working
 if (!(food.x == snakeElements.Last().x && food.y == snakeElements.Last().y))
```

Isn't it all the same?

Comment: Aren't you comparing floats? Also, note that the two conditions are different

Comment: Those conditions are *not* equivalent!  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws -- you can't just move negation like that.

Comment: are x or y a custom object?

Comment: nope, struct containing two integers x and y

Comment: `Isn't it all the same?` - No.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) `(!a && !b)` is the same as `!(a || b)` so your first example should be:

```
if (food.x != snakeElements.Last().x || food.y != snakeElements.Last().y)
```

Comment: @Blorgbeard: While that's true, this is still the right path. The link and demonstration are useful. Not to mention the fact that we don't know which was the true goal, since the OP considered them equivalent.

Comment: @Magus we do know, because he said `// not working` and `// working`

Comment: @Blorgbeard: You're right, but I still think it's worth him testing his logic carefully, as these two are very different. When an important logic issue like this crops up, it's important to make sure your preconceptions weren't also wrong.

Answer (score 5):

The && should be || in the first if.

```
if (food.x != snakeElements.Last().x || food.y != snakeElements.Last().y)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you write out what you actually mean by your boolean condition, you can see more clearly what the difference is.

```
// not working
if (food.x != snakeElements.Last().x && food.y != snakeElements.Last().y)
```

This means:

> "The food is not in the same column as the last snake element, and the food is not in the same row as the last snake element"

The logic error is a bit more obvious now. What if the food's position is (10,3), and the last element's position is (14,3)?

Compare with:

```
// working
if (!(food.x == snakeElements.Last().x && food.y == snakeElements.Last().y))
```

Which means:

> "It's not true that (the food is in the same row as the last snake element and the food is in the same column as the last snake element)"

Now the condition is false if and only if the food has the same X **and** Y as the last snake element.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not same.

If this works...

```
if (!(food.x == snakeElements.Last().x && food.y == snakeElements.Last().y)) // working
```

Then this should work too...

```
if (food.x != snakeElements.Last().x || food.y != snakeElements.Last().y) // should work
```

Notice the change in the sign from logical AND (&&) to logical OR (||).

Answer (score 0):

I think the boolean logic is different in two cases:

1. both comparisons must be not equal for the if to evaluate to true.
2. either one has to be not equal for if to evaluate to true

Answer (score 0):

They are different.

To be clear, I'll call `food.x` as `X` and `snakeElements.Last().x` as `X'`, others as `Y` and `Y'`.

First one is saying:

> if `X` is different than `X'` **AND** `Y` is different than `Y' is true`

Second one is saying:

> if `X` is equal to `X'` **AND** `Y` is equal to `Y' is false`

Assume that `X`, `X'`, `Y`, `Y'` are integers

If we say that `X = 3, X' = 5, Y = 1, Y' = 4`, first statement is true, because `X != X'` `Y != Y'` are both true. However, second would also be true becase `X` is not equal to `X'`.